# Php sqlsrv_query & sqlsrv_fetch_array used on primary key with Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am having issues retrieving the primary key from a table.

My table structure is as follows.

[image]

In the table is a single record:

```
id = 1 
PlaceName = 'in the matrix'
```

[image]

Retrieved using the following SQL statement directly:

```
SELECT id 
FROM rde_613949.dbo.PlaceNames 
WHERE PlaceName = 'in the matrix';
```

I am attempting to retrieve the `id` of this record using the following method:

```
function GetPlaceNameId($locationName)
{
    //returns the id of the location name, creating if required
    $resource = sqlsrv_connect($this->Server,$this->ConnectionInfo);
    $tsql = "SELECT id from rde_613949.dbo.PlaceNames where PlaceName = ?";
    $options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($resource, $tsql, array($locationName), $options);
    if ($stmt)
    {
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC));
        {
            $recordFound = true;
            $locationId = $row['id'];
            return $locationId;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return $this -> AddPlaceToDatabase($locationName);
    }
}
```

This method fails at

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
```

`$row` returns as null, which means `$location` also returns as null.

I have another table with another method where this approach works. The only real difference is that I am not returning the primary key in the one that works.

```
public function FindStudentRecord($studentId)
{
    require_once("./Student.php");
    $resource = sqlsrv_connect($this->Server,$this->ConnectionInfo);
    $tsql = "select FirstName, LastName from rde_613949.dbo.Students where StudentId = ?";
    $options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $result = sqlsrv_query($resource, $tsql, array($studentId), $options);
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $student = new Student($studentId, $row['FirstName'], $row['LastName']);
        return $student;
    }
    return null; //no records found return null
}
```

[image]

Please can someone explain the difference in this situation to me and advise me how to do this correctly, please?

Comment: What is the collation of the `PlaceName` column? And what does `GetPlaceNameId('in the matrix')` call return?

Comment: I don't know how to get a collate for the collum. But as I never set a collate it should be the default. The table and collum were created with the following code. `function CreatePlacesTable()
    {
        $createQuery = 'create table Places 
        (
            id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
            PlaceName varchar (200) NOT NULL
        )';
        $query = sqlsrv_prepare($this->Resource, $createQuery);
        return sqlsrv_execute($query);
    }`  In answer to your second question it gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

While I do not understand why I got around this by selecting * instead of selecting id. If anyone understands this please do a post to advise.

Comment: A possible explanation is the database collation. You may check the collation with `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('rde_613949', 'Collation')`. In case of a case-sensitive collation, `Id` and `id` are different column names.